# Rails: how to convert interpolated image_tag from string in model to html link

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This may be convoluted, but I need a way to convert an interpolated image_tag from a model in a text column to show the image after converting the data to ERb.

My model has this for a text entry

```
"This is the one where I try to see if image functionality is possible within the text here. \#{image_tag 'http://goo.gl/wqyq7N'}"
```

I put the forward slash since the model wouldn't take my text otherwise.

Then my controller "entries_controller.rb":

```
def index
  @entries = Entry.all.order('created_at DESC')
end
```

Then my view "entries/index.html.erb":

```
<div>
  <% @entries.each do |entry| %>
      <p class="lead"><%= entry.created_at.to_date.to_formatted_s(:rfc822) %></p>
      <h2 class="center"><%= entry.title %></h2>
      <p><%= entry.content %></p>
      <hr>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

The result just puts "#{...}" with the link onto the page instead of putting the image_tag. Is there a way to undo the backslash to re-interpolate the variable?

I'm totally aware that this may be the wrong way to do what I'm trying to do, thus I'm open to any and all (good) suggestions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems with what you are trying to do:

1. String interpolations shouldn't be escaped, they are meant to be run immediately as the string is encountered in the code. If you want to run that later, you need to `eval` the string:

   ```
   final_string = eval('"' + your_escaped_string + '"')
   ```

   It is also necessary to re-double-quote the string, that's why I have added the `'"'` before and after the string
2. the `image_tag` helper is useful to generate `<img>` tags for images in your application, as it will correctly generate the image URL for all your environments. If you already have the URL of the image, and it is external to your application, you can directly use an `<img>` tag:

   ```
   <img src='http://goo.gl/wqyq7N'>
   ```

   If you do this you won't need to add any string interpolation.

Please note that you will also have to call `.html_safe` on your string, or the HTML tag will anyway be escaped for security reasons.

Comment: Thanks! Looks like I'll be using HTML in the strings for the model then using <%= entry.content.html_safe %> in the view. I didn't need the eval method, but I'll keep it in mind if I could use it in the future.